# Why am I receiving "404 cannot POST" error from my Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express

so i have an express server that i'm using to handle webhook updates. i have it running on a port, and that port i have a server config for a ProxyPass at a subpage of a domain (domain.com/help/webhook).

```
<Location /help/webhook>
   ProxyPass  http://localhost:PORT/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:PORT/
</Location>
```

and i can get the root route just fine (it'll send back a 200 response with some text). but when i try to make a `POST` to the other route (domain.com/help/webhook/update) i get a 404 `cannot POST //update` error back. here's my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
let child_process = require('child_process'),
user = process.env.GITHUB_USER,
port = process.env.WEBHOOK_PORT;

let app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('this is the cherwell app webhook endpoint. nothing to see here.');
});

app.post('/update', (req, res) => {
        let sender = req.body.sender,
        branch = req.body.ref;
        console.log('request received');
        if(branch.indexOf('master') > -1 && sender.login === user) {
                child_process.exec('./deploy.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                        if(err) {
                                console.error(err);
                                return res.send(500);
                        } else {
                                console.log('success');
                                res.send(200);
                        }
                });
        }
});

app.listen(port);
```

in GitHub, setting up the webhook and delivering the payload, this is the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST //update</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

any idea what this issue might be? i wrote this from a tutorial on webhooks online, and it seemed simple enough though it being my first time deploying an app, i may be missing something either on the server configuration side or in my express code. i dunno which.

thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the URL that is being posted to is `//update` rather than `/update`. You should add a trailing slash to your location argument.

From the docs on `mod_proxy`:

> If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: ohhh i see. i let my admin know to make that change and it seemed to work. thank you!